# What makes this prime factorization so efficient?

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

I've been doing some Project Euler problems to learn/practice Lua, and my initial quick-and-dirty way of finding the largest prime factor of `n`was pretty bad, so I looked up some code to see how others were doing it (in attempts to understand different factoring methodologies).

I ran across the following (originally in Python - this is my Lua):

```
function Main()
    local n = 102
    local i = 2
    while i^2 < n do
        while n%i==0 do n = n / i end
        i = i+1
    end
    print(n)
end
```

This factored huge numbers in a **very** short time - almost immediately. The thing I noticed about the algorithm that I wouldn't have divined:

- `n = n / i`

This seems to be in all of the decent algorithms. I've worked it out on paper with smaller numbers and I can see that it makes the numbers converge, but I don't understand why this operation converges on the largest prime factor.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Try this with a large prime such as n = 10^18 + 3. The algorithm is still O(sqrt(n)), when there are much more efficient factoring algorithms available

Comment: A rather simple one being the Pollard's rho algorithm with expected complexity O(n^(1/4))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `i` is the prime factor candidate. Consider, `n` is composed of the following prime numbers:

```
n = p1^n1 * p2^n2 * p3^n3
```

When `i` reaches `p1`, the statement `n = n / i = n / p1` removes one occurrence of `p1`:

```
n / p1 = p1^(n-1) * p2^n2 * p3^n3
```

The inner `while` iterates as long as there are `p1`s in `n`. Thus, after the iteration is complete (when `i = i + 1` is executed), all occurrences of `p1` have been removed and:

```
n' =  p2^n2 * p3^n3
```

Let's skip some iterations until `i` reaches `p3`. The remaining `n` is then:

```
n'' = p3^n3
```

Here, we find a first mistake in the code. If `n3` is 2, then the outer condition does not hold and we remain with `p3^2`. It should be `while i^2 <= n`.

As before, the inner `while` removes all occurences of `p3`, leaving us with `n'''=1`. This is the second mistake. It should be `while n%i==0 and n>i` (not sure about the LUA syntax), which keeps the very last occurence.

So the above code works for all numbers `n` where the largest prime factor occurrs only once by successivley removing all other factors. For all other numbers, the mentioned corrections should make it work, too.

Answer (score 0):

This eliminates all the known smaller prime factors off `n` so that `n` becomes smaller, and `sqrt(n)` can be reached earlier. This gives the performance boost, as you no longer need to run numbers to square root of original N, say if `n` is a million, it consists of 2's and 5's, and naive querying against all known primes would need to check against all primes up to 1000, while dividing this by 2 yields 15625, then dividing by 5 yields 1 (**by the way, your algorithm will return 1!** To fix, if your loop exits with n=1, return `i` instead.) effectively factoring the big number in two steps. But this is only acceptable with "common" numbers, that have a single high prime denominator and a bunch of smaller ones, but factoring a number `n=p*q` whiere both `p` and `q` are primes and are close won't be able to benefit from this boost.

The `n=n/i` line works because if you are seeking another prime than `i` you are currently found as a divisor, the result is also divisible by that prime, by definition of prime numbers. Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic . Also this only works in your case because your `i` runs from 2 upward, so that you first divide by primes then their composites. Otherwise, if your number would have a 3 as largest prime, is also divisible by 2 and you'd check against 6 first, you'd spoil the principle of only dividing by primes (say with 72, if you first divide by 6, you'll end up with 2, while the answer is 3) by accidentally dividing by a composite of a largest prime.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm (when corrected) takes O(max(p2,sqrt(p1))) steps to find the prime factorization of n, where p1 is the largest prime factor and the p2 is the second largest prime factor. In case of a repeated largest prime factor, p1=p2.

Knuth and Trabb Pardo studied the behavior of this function ["Analysis of a Simple Factorization Algorithm"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900505) Theoretical Computer Science 3 (1976) 321-348. They argued against the usual analysis such as computing the average number of steps taken when factoring integers up to n. Although a few numbers with large prime factors boost the average value, in a cryptographic context what may be more relevant is that some of the percentiles are quite low. For example, 44.7% of numbers satisfy `max(sqrt(p1),p2)<n^(1/3)`, and 1.2% of numbers satisfy `max(sqrt(p1),p2)<n^(1/5)`.

A simple improvement is to test the remainder for primality after you find a new prime factor. It is very fast to test whether a number is prime. This reduces the time to O(p2) by avoiding the trial divisions between p2 and sqrt(p1). The median size of the second largest prime is about n^0.21. This means it is feasible to factor many 45-digit numbers rapidly (in a few processor-seconds) using this improvement on trial division. By comparison, Pollard-rho factorization on a product of two primes takes O(sqrt(p2)) steps on average, according to one model.